# Firestore transactions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Why does Firestore require read operations to be executed before write operations? I understand that in general reads should be checked in transactions, whether some other transaction is also accessing data but is there some more in-depth explanation?

Comment: *Why does Firestore require for reads operations to be executed before write operations?* - Where did you read that?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions
Transaction failure chapter

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take some actions according to the value of a particular field, then you can use transactions. This means that the value of that field is read first and right after that is updated according to your logic. This is because a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with the server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully.

If you don't care about what exists in the particular field and you want to increment a counter for example, then you can simply use [increment(your_number)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value). This operation doesn't require a round trip with the Firebase servers, it simply just increments the value.

Comment: Hey, pazohl. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?